# NSArray filled with UIImages

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsarray

I'm trying to add images to my `UICollectionView`

Filling it this way:

```
NSArray *imagesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"], nil];
```

Each image has 3 resolutions @1x.png @2x.png and @3x.png

But it appears that `imagesArray` contains @1x image for all devices.

How can I solve it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can try removing the extension of the image names. [UIImage imageNamed:@"star"], etc. See if that works.

Comment: @GeneCode it didn't help :(

Comment: Do you actually have `star.png`, `star@2x.png` and `star@3x.png` all selected for your app target?

Comment: Do you test in actual device or simulator? In simulator, seems imageNamed is returning all x1 images even in iPad Retina.

Comment: If you are putting all resolutions image into your asset, then you won't be any issue. You just have to give @1x image name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Xcode cached @1x images. I cleaned up Build Folder and reinstalled my app.